# AJAX return data to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: 'inc/functions.php?func=get_usr&id='+usr, //Where to make Ajax calls
        success:function(data){
            if (data.fname) {
             var fname = data.fname;
             //alert (fname);
            $('#rname').text(fname);
            }
         },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
```

data returns:

```
fname: "test_fname"
lname: "test_lname"
role: "1"
```

problem is I can get `fname` out of it, the alert shows undefined.
This doesnt have to be serialized does it? i have this function working well on another project but i cant figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a malformed JSON response?

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `data` object?

Comment: {"fname":"Jeff","lname":"coldwell","role":"1"} is the response

Comment: (facepalm) dataType: "json", forgot to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding dataType: "json" seemed to fix the issue, it wasn't until i happened to rescan the code to see that i had remmed it out.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning the data in a data structure that jQuery knows how to parse. `data` will be a string so it won't have the properties you are trying to read.

You should use JSON instead.

Since you are making the request to a PHP script, do it like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode(Array(
    "fname" => "test_fname",
    "lname" => "test_lname",
    "role" => "1"
));
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `dataType: "json"` works, I don't know how I forgot it.

Comment: Given the data in the question (no `{`, no `,` and no `}`) forcing jQuery to ignore the content-type (which must be wrong if `dataType: "json" makes a difference) won't fix it.

Comment: @Quentin See the OP's comment below the question: The response is `{"fname":"Jeff","lname":"coldwell","role":"1"}`.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment below the question about the response, it's not entirely clear what the *exact* content of `data` is but perhaps the json has not been parsed yet.

You can do that automatically using the `dataType`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
    url: 'inc/functions.php?func=get_usr&id='+usr, //Where to make Ajax calls
    // here
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        if (data.fname) {
         var fname = data.fname;
         //alert (fname);
        $('#rname').text(fname);
        }
     },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       alert(thrownError);
    }
    });
```